# How to check id of a tagged user with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a command defined with my discord bot that responds to a prompt like shown:

`if message.content.startswith("doge roast") : print("<the roast>")`

This responds in all cases, but I would like to check whether I have been tagged in the post and respond differently in said case.

I've tried looking at some solutions, but they use command contexts. I have simply defined my command in `on_message`.

So, how would I find the id of the user that is tagged in the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

You can access the mentions in a `discord.Message` using the `mentions` property.

A list is stored in the `mentions` property, so you can access the tagged `discord.Member` using `message.mentions[0]`.

### Code

```py
if message.content.startswith("doge roast"):
    if message.mentions[0].id == YOUR_ID:
        print("something else")
    else:
        print("<the roast>")
```

Note: if using `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, you can replace `YOUR_ID` with `bot.owner_id`

### Reference

[`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)

[`Member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.id)

Answer (score 0):

So if you're using on_message, you could try something like this:

```
if message.content.startswith("doge roast"):
    if message.content.split(" ")[2].replace('<@','').replace('>','').replace('!','') == "YOUR ID":
        await message.channel.send("You can't roast this person!")
    else:
        await message.channel.send("<The roast>")
```

The above code will start by checking if you're using the doge roast command. It will then check the mention, and strip all characters inside it, turning that mention into a user id. This will allow it to check if it's trying to roast you. If the userid of the person they've mentioned is yours, then it will reply saying "you can't roast this person". If it isn't you, it will reply with the roast.

You can find your userid by reading [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPROrf4Fe3Q&ab_channel=KnowledgeBase)

Once you have your userid, replace "YOUR ID" with that ID.

Comment: heyy it really works and tysm!

Comment: No worries, happy to help!